# How to select specifics in a file and sort them

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

So to put it simply lets say have data in a  file that begins with

```
Start
47 Data
70 Data
60 Data
Finish

Start 
56 Data
86 Data
75 Data
Finish
```

How do I read in the file and have each data within the Start and Finish sorted respectively?

```
The Output would look liek

Start
47 Data
60 Data
70 Data
Finish

Start
56 Data
75 Data
86 Data
Finish
```

I really don't know how to apply the sort method selectively?

Comment: You write some code. If you don't know where to start, you do some research. If your code doesn't work, you debug it. If you really can't solve it, but can reduce it to a [mcve], *then* you can ask here.

Comment: Well I did some research and I have been coding it and it isn't working. The data I am working with is really complicated and decided to make it really simple and posted it here. I didn't post any code or the actual set I am using because it would shun people away from the problem.

Comment: Why do you think that? Give a [mcve], as recommended in [ask]. In general, people would rather help when you show some effort.

Comment: It does, and generally I show what I have done and the code I have so far.  It was a simple question that was asked and someone has answered simply so I can check out the logic and apply that logic back to my code.

Comment: Your question shows zero effort on your part. Please note that SO isn't a code-writing or tutorial service. You were fortunate enough to get an answer, but a set of requirements is **not a good question**. Please don't do it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could make a list of lists, store each block in a list, then sort all lists:

```
data = []
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for l in f:
        l = l.strip()
        if l:  # discard empty lines
            if l=="Start":
                # create a new list
                data.append([])
            elif l=="Finish":  # we don't really need that tag, we have "Start"
                pass
            else:
                data[-1].append(l)  # append to current list (last one)

# list comprehension to order sub-lists
sorted_data = [sorted(d) for d in data]

# print sorted in console
for d in data:
    print("Start")
    for i in d:
        print(i)
    print("Finish\n")
```